# How do I add jQuery to a submit button which fires before Paypal objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, paypal

I have a Paypal Digital Express form which works fine. However, I would like to add a bit of jQuery to the submit button which will fire -before- the Paypal popup window opens and can prevent the Paypal code from firing. Unfortunately, the Paypal window always open first.

```
  jQuery('#buyLink').click( function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        // if no boxes are checked; no songs selected
        if ( jQuery("#buysongs input:checkbox:checked").length == 0) {  
            alert('Please select at least one song!');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to prioritise my code so that it fires -before- the Paypal code?

EDIT: I added e.preventDefault() per the first answer, but what that does is:
a) the popup window still opens but 
b) the Paypal site is never reached.

Instead, it displays the calling page in the popup.

So... I want to prevent that Paypal popup window from opening. Perhaps I need to change the 'action' on the form and trigger that action from inside my jQuery? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the preventDefault() function:

```
jQuery('#buyLink').click( function(event) { 

    event.preventDefault();

    if (jQuery("#buysongs input:checkbox:checked").length == 0) {  
        alert('Please select at least one song!');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        // submit form
    }

});
```

Comment: What that does is: a) the popup window still opens but b) the Paypal site is never reached. Instead, it displays the calling page in the popup.

Comment: @jchwebdev It would be easier to understand why that's happening if we could see rest of the code, but I can understand if you don't want to post it for security reasons. An easy alternative would be to hide or disable the buy link altogether if they don't have any songs selected.